# EF Core - Concurrent saving of the same entity creates multiple

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

**The Problem**
My concept is that when a user creates a post with some tags, the server first checks if the tag name already exists, if it does, it's counter is incremented, otherwise a new tag is created. 
The problem comes when multiple users create a post at the same time, with a new tag, lets say `new_tag`, then multiple tags of the same name get persisted in the database instead of 1 tag with counter = # of users who used this tag

As you can see for each user, a new tag record is created in the database:

```
--------------------------------
|  id  |  tagName  |  counter  |
|------|-----------|-----------|
|   1  |  new_tag  |    1      |
|   2  |  new_tag  |    1      |
|   3  |  new_tag  |    1      |
|   4  |  new_tag  |    1      |
--------------------------------
```

What I expect:

```
--------------------------------
|  id  |  tagName  |  counter  |
|------|-----------|-----------|
|   1  |  new_tag  |    4      |
--------------------------------
```

This code shows how I implemented the persistence:

**PostRepository**

```
public async Task<bool> AddAsync(Post entity)
        {
            await AddNewTagsAsync(entity);
            _context.Attach(entity.Event);
            await _context.AddAsync(entity);
            await _context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();
                var result = await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            _context.Database.CommitTransaction();
                return result > 0;
        }

 public async Task AddNewTagsAsync(Post post)
        {
            // store tags name in lower case
            if ((post.PostTags == null) || (post.PostTags.Count==0))
                return;
            post.PostTags.ForEach(pt => pt.Tag.TagName = pt.Tag.TagName.ToLower());

            for(var i =0; i<post.PostTags.Count; i++)
            {
                var postTag = post.PostTags[i];

                // here lays the main problem, when many concurrent users check for tag existence 
                // all get null and new tag will be created, workaround needed!
                var existingTag = await _context.Tags.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.TagName == postTag.Tag.TagName);

                // if tag exists, increment counter
                if (existingTag != null)
                {
                    existingTag.Counter++;
                    postTag.Tag = existingTag;
                    continue;
                }

               // else the new Tag object will be peristed   
            }
        }
```

This is a piece of my ER Diagram:
[image: This]


Just to mention, it works as expected if one user creates the tag first, then others are just incrementing the counter and use the same tag

Comment: Dumb question, but doesn't the number of `PostTags` entries actually represent the counter you are looking for? However, you might want to take a look at locking techniques with EF, e.g. [Handling Concurrency Conflicts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency).

Comment: In processor time, there is an era between `_context.Tags.SingleOrDefaultAsync...` and `CommitTransaction`. This type of conflict can only be solved by a unique database index and catching exceptions.

Comment: @GertArnold the problem is, no exception is thrown. All threads see that this tag does not exist and they create it.

Comment: @GertArnold Should I place an index on the tagname column?

Comment: @Gene Technically, I can count the tag occurrence from post tags, but for performance reasons I decided to stick to this implementation.

Comment: "All threads see that this tag does not exist" -- That's what I mean. They have plenty of time to come to that conclusion. So yes, an index is necessary to make it ultimately safe.

Comment: I can tell the code is written very poorly. First of you should create unique constraint for TagName. Second you should use Unit of Work.

Comment: @akd Good idea!

Comment: I think that keeping the count manually is unnecessary, with an index, the count in PostTags filtering by tagid would take a negligible time even if they were millions of rows. Also a unique index on TagName would avoid duplicates. You should only handle the exceptions.

Comment: @akd Would be interesting to hear how UoW would solve this, esp. since they already have a UoW.

Comment: @GertArnold not quite sure about whether they do. And not sure why they need to use Database.CommitTransation? This whole thing should be atomic. First you’d check if the tag exist or not if not then create one if yes then increment the number. Whole thing in a single transaction where between begin transaction and commit transaction. Begin transaction would lock any other thread. So you wouldn’t end up with the issue they are having.

Comment: Well that’s why I said the code is written very poorly in my view:) that whole dB access and dB commits , attach etc shouldn’t be part of your code. That should be handled by UoW. Your code should only do 2 things as atomic. Check if the tag exist if no create new entity if yes increment the number in the same transaction. That’s all! The rest is UoW work task.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for an atomic UPSERT statement (a combined UPDATE or INSERT).

UPSERTS are not supported by EF Core. See: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/4526

However, if you're willing to forgo change tracking, you can directly make a SQL merge statement, like this:

```
    MERGE INTO dbo.Tags AS target  
        USING (VALUES ({TagName})) AS source (TagName)  
        ON target.TagName = source.TagName  
    WHEN MATCHED THEN  
        UPDATE SET Counter = Counter + 1  
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN  
        INSERT (TagName, Counter) VALUES (TagName, 1);
```

You might call it something like this:

```
public async Task AddNewTagsAsync(Post post)
{
    foreach (var tag in post.PostTags)
    {
        await _context.Database.ExececuteInterpolatedAsync($@"
            MERGE INTO dbo.Tags AS target  
                USING (VALUES ({tag.TagName})) AS source (TagName)  
                ON target.TagName = source.TagName  
            WHEN MATCHED THEN  
                UPDATE SET Counter = Counter + 1  
            WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN  
                INSERT (TagName, Counter) VALUES (TagName, 1)");
    } 
}
```